# How do I get sed to match a pattern with multiple exceptions?

Tags: sed

Consider the following config file

```
; My Config
;

[CITY]
URL='my.city.com'
ID='1234'
PID='1'

[SITE]
URL='my.site.com'
ID='2345'
PID='2'

[UNIT]
URL='my.unit.com'
ID='3456'
PID='3'

[BOB]
URL='my.bob.com'
ID='123456'
PID='15'

. . .
```

My goal is to strip all the fields past the first three.  The first three have fixed names, the others are variable.  I came close with:

```
sed -e '/.*\[[^DUC].*\]/Q' test.conf
```

Which gave me what I wanted:

```
; My Config
;

[CITY]
URL='my.city.com'
ID='1234'
PID='1'

[SITE]
URL='my.site.com'
ID='2345'
PID='2'

[UNIT]
URL='my.unit.com'
ID='3456'
PID='3'
```

But it fails if the first name past these three starts with 'C', 'S' or 'U'.  What I'm really looking for is a way to do a negative comparison against the three strings "CITY", "SITE" and "UNIT".  Is there a way to do that with sed, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -pe 'exit if /\[(?!(?:CITY|SITE|UNIT)\]).*\]/' test.conf
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line and prints each line after processing;
- `(?!pattern)` is a [negative look-ahead assertion](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#(?!pattern)), i.e. it says "pattern doesn't follow", but consumes no characters. `BOB` in this example is consumed by the `.*` because the negative look-ahead succeeds.
- `(?:pattern)` is just for grouping, it doesn't capture anything.

Comment: Thank you!
Just a small modification: perl -pe 'exit if /\\[(?!CITY\\]|SITE\\]|UNIT\\]).*\\]/' test.conf

Comment: You are right. You can shorten it to `/\[(?!(?:CITY|SITE|UNIT)\]).*\]/` using a non-matching group to avoid the repetition of the ``\]``.

Answer (score 3):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '/^\[/ && (++c > 3){exit} 1' file
; My Config
;

[CITY]
URL='my.city.com'
ID='1234'
PID='1'

[SITE]
URL='my.site.com'
ID='2345'
PID='2'

[UNIT]
URL='my.unit.com'
ID='3456'
PID='3'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\[/{:a;n;/\S/ba;x;s/^/x/;/xxx/Q;x}' file
```

Each time a `[` at the start of a line is encountered, make a note in the hold  space, and quit after the third.

Comment: I'd do this with `'/^\[/ { x;/xxx/Q;s/$/x/;x }'`

Comment: @jthill you can but there is a subtle difference.